# GitHub Actions runing build and unit test coverage report

Tags: github, jestjs, code-coverage, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a GitHub Action to run build and coverage report using Jest but the workflow that I have set up seems wrong:

```yaml
# Configure integration.

name:  Build

# Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events
on: [push, pull_request]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out the repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install dependencies
      - name: Install
        run: yarn install
      # Build the app
      - name: Build
        run: yarn build
      # Get test coverage
      - uses: ziishaned/jest-reporter-action@v0.0.1
          with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          test-command: 'yarn test:unit:coverage'
```

[GitHub Action that I used](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jest-code-coverage-report)

Comment: To be able to help you better, could uou explain exactly what is your problem? Does the workflow run? Did it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the `with` have two space more

```
      - uses: ziishaned/jest-reporter-action@v0.0.1
          with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          test-command: 'yarn test:unit:coverage'
```